# Creating a Curses menu bar in Python

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, curses

I'm using Python with the curses import for a console application. I'd like to add a typical Menu bar at the top. I've found a [couple](http://urwid.org) different [libraries](https://gist.github.com/lurch/2494781), as well as the Python built-in [panel](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.panel.html) feature for doing so, but since I'm pretty new to Python I'm wondering if there are better options out there? I just don't want to end up wrassling with something that isn't all that widely used or supported.

Comment: This should really belong on the software recs stack exchange. It is off-topic for stackoverflow as it is not asking about a specific programming problem but rather an off-site resource.

Comment: I really don't understand the logic behind this community sometimes. Asking about a current/preferred tool for software development is about as on-topic as it gets.

Comment: @wufoo No, [it is not on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Quoting: "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: [...] Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Serioulsy? Ok, how about this one guys?: "software tools commonly used by programmers practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"  Like I said, the logic of many on this forum is really baffling sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just skimmed the description of curses, so I don't know if it's relevant to you trying to implement a main menu, but I know a lot of people use tkinter.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_menu.htm

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm